# mvc Details recibe un valor nulo

Tags: c#, mvc, controller

Uso VS 2015. Tengo un listado de clientes. Cuando escojo uno, al llegar a Details noto que el campo nombre_usuario llega nulo.

```
private salon_de_belleza_bd2Entities db = new salon_de_belleza_bd2Entities();
 public ActionResult Index()
        {            
            return View(db.tbl_clientes.ToList());
        }

        // GET: Clientes/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(string nombre_usuario)
        {
            if (nombre_usuario == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
```

Uso procedimientos almacenados y data base first

Comment: Si **mostraras el codigo** de como envias el valor podriamos ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Si en la ruta por defecto de la aplicación, definida en App_Start/RouteConfig.cs, tienes algo similar a esto:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Posiblemente estés haciendo una petición tal que "Clientes/Details/5", pero el parámetro por defecto se llama "id".

Si este es el caso podrías hacer dos cosas, cambiar el nombre del parámetro del método "Details", de "nombre_usuario" a "id", o realizar una petición a "Clientes/Details?nombre_usuario=5"

Comment: Ya recibe el parámetro, pero sale este error:

Comment: El elemento de modelo pasado al diccionario es de tipo 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult`1[SalonDeBelleza.Models.mostrar_cliente_Result]', pero este diccionario requiere un elemento de modelo de tipo 'SalonDeBelleza.Models.tbl_clientes'.

Comment: Tu última pregunta no está relacionada a la pregunta original. Fórmula esta nueva pregunta en otro nuevo post